Single-word request: an adjective meaning "spatial OR temporal"
"Spatial" and "temporal" refer to space and time in common, everyday understanding.  I trust no further context is required, but let us say, for example, that I want a word that covers adverbs of both space and time (here, now, anywhere, anytime, etc).  I thought about "spatio-temporal" (or "loco-temporal"), but I would prefer a word that is not compound word.  Also, "space-time" has a specific meaning in physics.  Given that space and time are closely related concepts, is there a word that covers both?  Thanks in advance.
Edit:

Context:  Writing for a general audience, i.e. the general public,
in any non-fiction genre and media content.
Example:  Let us say that I am writing an article or web page about grammar, or giving a presentation to a composition workshop, and that the subject is adverbs.  Let us say that I want to contrast "spatial and/or  temporal" adverbs with one or more other categories of adverbs, and that I would be making reference to "spatial and/or  temporal" adverbs a lot.  Is there a word (other than "spatio-temporal" or "spatiotemporal") that I can use in place of "spatial and/or temporal"?


Are you asking about a word to cover both terms in advanced physics? Or  in everyday life? If in advanced physics, we have a site for that at [physics.se].

Those terms are not in everyday common use. Few people ask "how are your spatial and temporal awareness today?" Please give an example of how you intend to use the single word.

Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/589819

I've voted to close with the "easily answered by a dictionary" reason: I find the word "spatiotemporal" (not strictly compound) defined in several dictionaries.

@AndyBonner Your vote was disingenuous. Leaving aside that closed compound words are compound words, I said I was looking for a word other than "spatiotemporal".

Disingenuous? I feel like I was pretty up-front. But I feel like, when there is a word which seems to have exactly the desired meaning, a word-request question needs to explain more about why that word isn't suitable. Possibly the sample sentence that the other close-votes asked for would help with that.

@AndyBonner You implied that I couldn't be bothered to look up whether "spatiotemporal" was in the dictionaries.

@AndyBonner, if there is no word that satisfies the OP's requirements (which in this case includes its being something other than spatio-temporal), then the question is not answerable by a dictionary. Such questions are sometimes closed on the ground that the requirements themselves are contrived, but that is not the case here.

The question leaves an impression that the OP's reasons for rejecting spatio-temporal are stylistic, but when one takes into account which answer was eventually accepted, it appears that something else may have been at work as well: spatio-temporal usually means spatial-and-temporal, while the OP really needs a term that means spatial-or-temporal.

Consider deictic, defined at dictionary.com as follows in its second entry:

deictic
adjective
2. Grammar. specifying identity or spatial or temporal location from the perspective of one or more of the participants in an act of speech or writing, in the context of either an external situation or the surrounding discourse, as we, you, here, there, now, then, this, that, the former, or the latter.

Here's the term used in the title and abstract of a paper available from ResearchGate:

Deictic Markers in Standard English and Standard Arabic: A Contrastive Study


The concept of deixis or deictic markers which means "pointing to" is a linguistic phenomenon manifested in most human languages. It includes some expressions which refer to persons, places and times that need to be appointed. And this is done by referring to the place and time of happening and persons involved in it. Deixis is a term used in linguistic theory to subsume those features of language which refer directly to the personal, locational, and temporal characteristics of the situation within which an utterance takes place and whose meaning is relative to that situation, e.g., I/you, here/there, this/that, now/then are deictic expressions (Crystal, 1991:96). The present paper tries to answer the following questions: 1. How deictic markers are linguistically realized in English and Arabic. 2. Are deictic markers syntactically and semantically similar or different in English and Arabic?


While this word is well suited to such, relatively specialised contexts, it is not something that could be readily used outside them. There seems to be a conflict between the OP's saying that the word is to be used in writing for 'the general public' and then using an example of 'giving a presentation to a composition workshop'.

For example, my theoretical physics degree did not include this word, and I had never heard it before today.

Moreover, as the quoted texts make clear, only the specifications of spatial/temporal locations that are relative to the speaker or addressee are called deictic (or indexical), the specifications of spatial/temporal locations in absolute, neutral terms would not be labelled deictic. The OP's acceptance of the answer indicates that the former is what the OP had in mind, but the actual wording of the question implied that the latter was to be included (while now is deictic, anywhere, by itself, is not).

@jsw29 I was hoping for a more general and absolute term, but I think this is the best that I'm going to get.  I must have also been grateful for an attempt at an answer, as opposed to people trying to close down the question.

"Space" and "Time" are related concepts in advanced physics, but not in everyday life. In everyday life there is therefore no word meaning both, any more than there is a word that means both "cat" and "banana".
In advanced physics the best word is probably "spatio-temporal". It's relatively well known (pun intended) and gets wide sci-fi usage. "Dimensional" might work, but it can cover a lot of other meanings.

It should perhaps be added that, although spatio-temporal is mostly used in scientific (and sci-fi) contexts, somebody who encounters it for the first time doesn't need a specialised training in advanced physics to figure out its meaning, as it is made out of relatively familiar components.
